# Trouble looping through Posts using Blade Templating Engine with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel and php altogether, I have the following problem.
I am trying to loop through users posts, displaying their "usernames" only if "display names" are not set. For that I have done this:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    {{
       $username = $post->user->username;
       $display_name = display_name_of($username);
       $display_name == "" ? $author = $post->username : $author = $display_name;
    }}

    <h4>By {{$author}}</h4>
```

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Blade documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates):

```
{{ $name or 'Default' }}
```

You seem to have a lot of logic in your view, try to separate some of it into a [presenter](https://github.com/laracasts/Presenter).

Answer (score 0):

Ok this seems to work but I know there's a cleaner way:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
        <h4>By {{display_name_of($post->user->username) == "" ? $post->user->username : display_name_of($post->user->username);}}</h4>
@endforeach
```